# How can I update FontFamily and Foreground of a data bound ListBox using INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

### Scenario

I have Two Classes:

- `Fruit` has two data members `FruitName` and `FruitColor`
- `Presentation` also has two members `ForeColor`and `FontName`

A ListBox's `ItemsSource` property is set to `List<Fruit>`. And the fruits are listed.

However, I want to change FontFamily and Foreground of the TextBlock control, which should reflect immediately as I set the Presentation instance to the ListBox.

### Problem

The problem is that

- When I am calling the `btnChangeColor_Click()`, I receive an exception "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**". In the `INotifyPropertyChanged()` method. Exactly here...

  await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
  {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  });

I want to set ListBox with some Fruits object showing FruitName and FruitColor. I also want to change font names and the foreground of the TextBlock showing the FruitName and the FruitColor, so that changing the color and font name should reflect immediately

### Code

TestingRealTimeUIUpdate.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="dataStorage_And_AppSettings.TestingRealTimeUIUpdate"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:dataStorage_And_AppSettings"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="lstFruits" Height="400" Background="Aqua">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="lblFruitName" Text="{Binding Fruits.FruitName}" Foreground="{Binding Presentations.ForeColor}" FontFamily="{Binding Presentations.FontName}" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="lblFruitColor" Text="{Binding Fruits.FruitColor}" Foreground="{Binding Presentations.ForeColor}" FontFamily="{Binding Presentations.FontName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
            <ListBox x:Name="lstColors" Height="175" Background="Goldenrod" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="lblFruitName" Text="FontColors And Font Name" Foreground="{Binding Presentation.ForeColor}" FontFamily="{Binding Presentation.FontName}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <Button x:Name="btnReloadFruits" Content="ReloadBasket" Click="btnReload_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="btnChangeColor" Content="ChangeColor" Click="btnChangeColor_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The TestingRealTimeUIUpdate.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace dataStorage_And_AppSettings
{
    public sealed partial class TestingRealTimeUIUpdate : Page
    {
        private Comp FruitBasket;
        private List<Presentation> PresentationForFruitBasket = new List<Presentation>
        {
            new Presentation { FontName = "Arial", ForeColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) },
            new Presentation { FontName = "Verdana", ForeColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow) },
            new Presentation { FontName = "Times New roman", ForeColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown) },
            new Presentation { FontName = "Tahoma", ForeColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) },
        };

        private List<Fruit> FruitForFruitBasket = new List<Fruit>
        {
            new Fruit { FruitName= "Mango", FruitColor="Yellow" },
            new Fruit {FruitName = "Banana", FruitColor= "Yellow" },
            new Fruit { FruitName="Grapes", FruitColor="Green"},
            new Fruit {FruitName="Tomato", FruitColor="Red" }
        };

        public TestingRealTimeUIUpdate()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnReload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Comp> lstFruitBasket = new List<Comp>();
            foreach( var item in FruitForFruitBasket)
            {
                FruitBasket = new Comp();
                FruitBasket.Fruits = item;
                FruitBasket.Presentations = PresentationForFruitBasket.ElementAt(2);
                lstFruitBasket.Add(FruitBasket);
            }   
            lstFruits.ItemsSource = lstFruitBasket;
        }

        private void btnChangeColor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            FruitBasket.Presentations = PresentationForFruitBasket.ElementAt(rnd.Next(0, 3));
        }
    }

    public class Comp : BindableBase
    {
        Fruit fruits = new Fruit();
        Presentation presentations = new Presentation();

        public Fruit Fruits
        {
            get { return fruits; }
            set { SetProperty(ref fruits, value); }
        }

        public Presentation Presentations
        {
            get { return presentations; }
            set { SetProperty(ref presentations, value); }
        }
    }

    public class Fruit:BindableBase
    {
        private string fruitname;
        private string fruitcolor;
        public string FruitName
        {
            get { return fruitname; }
            set { SetProperty(ref fruitname, value); }
        }
        public string FruitColor
        {
            get { return fruitcolor; }
            set { SetProperty(ref fruitcolor, value); }
        }
    }

    public class Presentation : BindableBase
    {
        private SolidColorBrush forecolor;
        private string fontname;
        public SolidColorBrush ForeColor
        {
            get { return forecolor; }
            set { SetProperty(ref forecolor, value); }
        }

        public string FontName
        {
            get { return fontname; }
            set { SetProperty(ref fontname, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

The BindableBase.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Windows.UI.Core;

namespace IQ.Main.ViewModels
{
    public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private CoreDispatcher dispatcher;
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            storage = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        internal virtual async void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare a variable of type presentation in your fruit class. Use that for binding.

Comment: You can't bind list box with two types of object. It has to be collection of same type

Comment: Thanks @Archana for commenting! Does it mean that I add the members of the Presentations class into the Fruit class. Or Should I add Presentation class as a member of the Fruit class itself? All I want is to change the FontFamily, Foreground of the items of the ListBox without reloading it.

Comment: Add presentation class as a member of fruit class

Comment: Are you trying to make each item's foreground and fontfamily changing according to each content (Fruit) ?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Thanks Grace for the comment! Not each item's individually. However, I don't want to put the fontfamily and foreground with fruits. For instance, when the (Fruit) data is bound to the list. If I want to change the fontfamily and foreground of the items of the list, I wish to do it without changing it in the Fruit class and rebound it to the list. That change is applied to all the items in the list, not to an individual item. (English is not my first language, I hope I conveyed what I want clearly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<ListBox Foreground="{x:Bind Foreground}" />
```

> This works if the Foreground property is in your code-behind.

You can do something like this:

```
<ListBox Foreground="{Binding Foreground}" />
```

> This works if the Foreground property is in your view-model.

You can also do this:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

> This works if the Foreground property is in your model

Remember, you can always create a composite object. Like this:

```
class MyObject
{
    public FruitObject Fruit { get; set; }
    public PresentationObject Presentation { get; set; }
}
```

> This will let you pass in multiple objects to any `ItemControl`.

Make sense? Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry for the answer. I tried the Composite object solution already. I wasn't able update the presentation of the ListBox. I have updated the question with an exact error message. The error is in 'INotifyPropertyChange()' method and I can't really figure out why the value is null.